# Cases bugged - lines overlapping

Tags: cases, bugs

The following code overlaps equations:

```
  $$U(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    - \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x} & \text{gdy}  \lambda \neq 1
    \\
    \ln x & \text{gdy}  \lambda =1 
    \end{cases}  $$
```

[image]

with following body:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{txfonts}

%\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Rozdział}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Spis treści}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Spis rysunków}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Spis tabel}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografia}

\pagestyle{headings}

\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20cm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja} % przykład nowego środowiska 
\newtheorem{example}{Przykład}[chapter] % przykład nowego środowiska 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Wniosek}[chapter] % przykład nowego środowiska 



\begin{document}
```

What is wrong with this document as it displays properly with another body?

Comment: Welcome! I can't reproduce the issue, with or without `babel`. Can you show a document that does?

Comment: Please see my file: https://ufile.io/rcy8idim

Comment: Your link is not accessible. Please edit your question  provide merge complete compilable but small document, which will reproduce your problem.  From showed code fragments is not possible reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko it is possible to reproduce with a few guesses:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, well, I'm not good in guessing :-). I test combination of bot OP's code fragments and result was ok.

Comment: @Zarko yes actually although I correctly guessed the root cause `\lineskiplimit` was negative, it wasn't very useful until the OP posted the example. I should search it is hard to believe that it's never been reported before `\k` is completely broken in the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`txfonts` has a bug in its definition of the ogonek, it leaves an ungrouped `\ooalign` so any character with an ognoek messes up the spacing from then on.

that could be fixed,but essentially the package has been superseded by `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`  and replacing

```
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

fixes the issue.

---

I downloaded your test file (it would have been better to add it to the question) and removing extra lines cones to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

następującą postać:
$$U(x) = 
\begin{cases}
- \frac{1}{1-\lambda } x^{1-\lambda} & \text{gdy}  \lambda \neq 0
\\
x & \text{gdy}  \lambda =0 
\end{cases}  $$


\end{document}
```

which shows the bad result unless you remove `txfonts` I'll trace a bit more.

Meanwhile you could use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead.

---

The problem can be reduced to a single character with an ognoeck if using txfonts package

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\showthe\lineskiplimit
ę
\showthe\lineskiplimit
\end{document}
```

---

You did not supply a test document, but in order to get the output shown you must have disabled line spacing in math displays, something equivalent to

[image]

which is the output from

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{txfonts}

%\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Rozdział}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Spis treści}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Spis rysunków}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Spis tabel}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografia}

\pagestyle{headings}

\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20cm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja}
\newtheorem{example}{Przykład}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Wniosek}[chapter] 



\begin{document}

\setbox\strutbox\null
\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
 $$U(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    - \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x} & \text{gdy}  \lambda \neq 1
    \\
    \ln x & \text{gdy}  \lambda =1 
    \end{cases}  $$

\end{document}
```